# desktop notification api for windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Are there any windows software that i can use that can connect with my website via API where there is a customizable feature for desktop notifications? 
Alternatively, are there any hacks i can use to make the width of the chrome desktop notification larger?

I tried using html but this just prints as a string.

```
function notifyMe() {
  if (!Notification) {
    alert('Notifications are supported in modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Firefox.'); 
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();

  var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
    icon: 'http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/media/image/j/i/Cumulus_2.jpg',
    body: "<div style='width:700px'>You've been notified!</div>",
  });

  notification.onclick = function () {
    window.open("http://www.google.com");      
  };
}
```

Any suggestions.. i want a customizable size notification?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the size of Chrome-provided notifications.

You can use an extension + [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to pass something to a native application of your choice (maybe through a "proxy" script, as Native Messaging is limited).

Comment: any recommendations of an application?

Comment: That would be [specifically off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.